# grep: How to use backreferences as quantificator?

Tags: regex, grep

For example I have strings

```
aeb107001234567
eeee**05**00**12345**00OTHERDATA000
eeee**08**00**12345678**00OTHERDATA
```

eeee is key
05 is length of strings
all strings in one line, (haven't \n or other separators, it's raw data)

I want to get string with length defined after eeee:

```
12345
12345678
```

I try to use grep -E:

```
echo str | grep -o -E "eeee.(.)00.{\1}"
```

I think it return  `eeee050012345` and `eeee080012345678`, but fail.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/146342/find-the-exact-string-with-grep

Comment: Do those `*`s REALLY exist in your input data? If not, remove them from your example. When you say `I think it return eeee050012345 and eeee080012345678` - are you saying that's your desired output or something else? When you say `all strings in one line, (haven't \n or other separators, it's raw data)` - are you saying that the input you're showing us which HAS newlines doesn't reflect your real data which DOESN'T have newlines? If so - fix your example again. Just show us an example of what you actually have for input and the expected output given that input.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that with a regular expression (of any flavour). But you can use `awk`, like this:

```
awk '{len=int(substr($0,5,2));print substr($0,0,len+8)}' file
```

We first separate the length from the string which are the characters 5 to 7. Having `len`, we can use `substr()` again to extract the string of interest. We are adding `8` to `len` because `eeee0500` has `8` characters.

Output:

```
eeee050012345
eeee080012345678
```

Comment: Sorry, I need to check match "eeee".  And i have this strings in one line.

Comment: Then why your question does not reflect that?